# Mounting using Autofs needs to reboot Nfs-server after rebooting the server

Tags: pi-3, mount, nfs

I have 2 RPis3 and nfs server 4, i used this tutorial for Autofs http://www.instructables.com/id/Reduce-overhead-due-to-network-drive-on-Raspberry-/?ALLSTEPS And it works but after restarting the server (pi) i try to access the mounting folder but i stuck for a long time and i don't get any files

And in the Rp server I've installed this package

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
```

after modifying exports file

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
```

I 've installed this package in Rp client

```
$sudo apt-get install autofs
```

and i added the following line at the end

/home/pi    /etc/mnt.autofs

i wrote in the autofs file,

```
nfsfiles  -fstype=nfs4  192.168.0.10:/remote/share
```

Start automounter

```
$sudo service autofs stop
$sudo service autofs start
```

at the end i open the folder to mount the files

```
$cd /home/pi/nfsfiles
$ls
```

after this steps it's working, but when i reboot the server, it doesn't work and i need to reboot the nfs-server